# How to start Activity in android

Tags: android

Hello I Have an Actvity like MainActicity1 and MainActicity2 and when eclipse start it loads MainActivity1 firstly. so, my question is that how can i start MainActivity2 in eclipse

Comment: Google it you will find a lot.

Comment: do you wanna start a2 from a1 or.. directly a2 ?  btw. pls google before you ask this kind of questions

Comment: if directly at app start than.. look in your manifest.xml

Answer (score 4):

just use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your manifest like this. Make your Mainactivity2 as launch activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stackoverflow"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                 </activity>

 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```